# Configuration of Solr 5 (Umlaute, special characters, and string length)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, full-text-search

Been running Solr 5 on a German site for the past few months and dealing with Umlaute appears to be a nightmare. I am not a specialist in Solr and on all other projects I am running elastic. It is a bit of an uphill battle to find your way through Solr documentation.

I am wondering if the following two things can be easily configured via schema.xml:

**1.) UMLAUTE and Special characters**

Special characters are stored in the Database in HTML code. For example: 
"an einer Außenwand. Eine Brandschutztür sorgt für maximale Sicherheit."

Now Solr does NOT in anyway know how to deal with it. So if a user searches for "für" nothing comes up. I also tried to search for "für" and for "fr" - nothing returns the expected result.

The same if I type in "Regelungs-App", nothing comes up - if I enter "Regelungs App" I get hits. Why does a simple dash throw Solr of its track? And what setting, or what can I do to ignore this?

**2.) Length of Search string**

If I search for a string within indexed content, it may be limited to a certain number of characters - example:

"Erreicht als einziger Staubemissionen" - no results
"als einziger Staubemissionen" - no results
"einziger Staubemissionen" - correct results
"Staubemissionen" - correct result

How can I set this?

My current schema.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->
<!--
 This is the Solr schema file. This file should be named "schema.xml" and
 should be in the conf directory under the solr home
 (i.e. ./solr/conf/schema.xml by default)
 or located where the classloader for the Solr webapp can find it.

 This example schema is the recommended starting point for users.
 It should be kept correct and concise, usable out-of-the-box.

 For more information, on how to customize this file, please see
 http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml

 PERFORMANCE NOTE: this schema includes many optional features and should not
 be used for benchmarking.  To improve performance one could
  - set stored="false" for all fields possible (esp large fields) when you
    only need to search on the field but don't need to return the original
    value.
  - set indexed="false" if you don't need to search on the field, but only
    return the field as a result of searching on other indexed fields.
  - remove all unneeded copyField statements
  - for best index size and searching performance, set "index" to false
    for all general text fields, use copyField to copy them to the
    catchall "text" field, and use that for searching.
  - For maximum indexing performance, use the StreamingUpdateSolrServer
    java client.
  - Remember to run the JVM in server mode, and use a higher logging level
    that avoids logging every request
-->
<schema name="sunspot" version="1.0">
  <types>
    <!-- field type definitions. The "name" attribute is
       just a label to be used by field definitions.  The "class"
       attribute and any other attributes determine the real
       behavior of the fieldType.
         Class names starting with "solr" refer to java classes in the
       org.apache.solr.analysis package.
    -->
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="rand" class="solr.RandomSortField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" stemEnglishPossessive="1" splitOnNumerics="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="tlong" class="solr.TrieLongField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <!-- *** This fieldType is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField"
               omitNorms="true"/>

    <fieldType name="daterange" class="solr.DateRangeField" omitNorms="true" />

    <!-- Special field type for spell correction. Be careful about
         adding filters here, as they apply *before* your values go in
         the spellcheck. For example, the lowercase filter here means
         all spelling suggestions will be lower case (without it,
         though, you'd have duplicate suggestions for lower and proper
         cased words). -->
    <fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <!-- A specialized field for geospatial search. If indexed, this fieldType must not be multivalued. -->
    <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
  </types>
  <fields>
    <!-- Valid attributes for fields:
     name: mandatory - the name for the field
     type: mandatory - the name of a previously defined type from the
       <types> section
     indexed: true if this field should be indexed (searchable or sortable)
     stored: true if this field should be retrievable
     compressed: [false] if this field should be stored using gzip compression
       (this will only apply if the field type is compressable; among
       the standard field types, only TextField and StrField are)
     multiValued: true if this field may contain multiple values per document
     omitNorms: (expert) set to true to omit the norms associated with
       this field (this disables length normalization and index-time
       boosting for the field, and saves some memory).  Only full-text
       fields or fields that need an index-time boost need norms.
     termVectors: [false] set to true to store the term vector for a
       given field.
       When using MoreLikeThis, fields used for similarity should be
       stored for best performance.
     termPositions: Store position information with the term vector.
       This will increase storage costs.
     termOffsets: Store offset information with the term vector. This
       will increase storage costs.
     default: a value that should be used if no value is specified
       when adding a document.
   -->
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="id" stored="true" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="type" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="class_name" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="text" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="lat" stored="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This field is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <field name="lng" stored="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="random_*" stored="false" type="rand" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="_local*" stored="false" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_text" stored="false" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_texts" stored="true" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_b" stored="false" type="boolean" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_bm" stored="false" type="boolean" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_bs" stored="true" type="boolean" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_bms" stored="true" type="boolean" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_d" stored="false" type="tdate" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dm" stored="false" type="tdate" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ds" stored="true" type="tdate" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dms" stored="true" type="tdate" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_e" stored="false" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_em" stored="false" type="tdouble" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_es" stored="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ems" stored="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_f" stored="false" type="tfloat" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_fm" stored="false" type="tfloat" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_fs" stored="true" type="tfloat" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_fms" stored="true" type="tfloat" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_i" stored="false" type="tint" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_im" stored="false" type="tint" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_is" stored="true" type="tint" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ims" stored="true" type="tint" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_l" stored="false" type="tlong" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_lm" stored="false" type="tlong" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ls" stored="true" type="tlong" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_lms" stored="true" type="tlong" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_s" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_sm" stored="false" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ss" stored="true" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_sms" stored="true" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_it" stored="false" type="tint" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_itm" stored="false" type="tint" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_its" stored="true" type="tint" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_itms" stored="true" type="tint" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ft" stored="false" type="tfloat" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ftm" stored="false" type="tfloat" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_fts" stored="true" type="tfloat" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ftms" stored="true" type="tfloat" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dt" stored="false" type="tdate" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dtm" stored="false" type="tdate" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dts" stored="true" type="tdate" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dtms" stored="true" type="tdate" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_textv" stored="false" termVectors="true" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_textsv" stored="true" termVectors="true" type="text" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_et" stored="false" termVectors="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_etm" stored="false" termVectors="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_ets" stored="true" termVectors="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_etms" stored="true" termVectors="true" type="tdouble" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_dr" stored="false" type="daterange" multiValued="false" indexed="true" />
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_drm" stored="false" type="daterange" multiValued="true" indexed="true" />
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_drs" stored="true" type="daterange" multiValued="false" indexed="true" />
    <!-- *** This dynamicField is used by Sunspot! *** -->
    <dynamicField name="*_drms" stored="true" type="daterange" multiValued="true" indexed="true" />

    <!-- Type used to index the lat and lon components for the "location" FieldType -->
    <dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="false" multiValued="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_p" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

    <dynamicField name="*_ll" stored="false" type="location" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_llm" stored="false" type="location" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_lls" stored="true" type="location" multiValued="false" indexed="true"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_llms" stored="true" type="location" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="textSpell" stored="false" type="textSpell" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>

    <!-- required by Solr 4 -->
    <field name="_version_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
  </fields>

  <!-- Field to use to determine and enforce document uniqueness.
      Unless this field is marked with required="false", it will be a required field
   -->
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <!-- field for the QueryParser to use when an explicit fieldname is absent -->
  <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
  <!-- SolrQueryParser configuration: defaultOperator="AND|OR" -->
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>
  <!-- copyField commands copy one field to another at the time a document
        is added to the index.  It's used either to index the same field differently,
        or to add multiple fields to the same field for easier/faster
        searching.  -->

  <!-- Use copyField to copy the fields you want to run spell checking
       on into one field. For example: -->
  <copyField source="*_text"  dest="textSpell" />
  <copyField source="*_s"  dest="textSpell" />
</schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say anything about the type of fields you're searching, but if it's of the type "text", the analysis chain looks unsuitable for what you're trying to do. The input (NGramTokenizer) and just lowercasing, will not give the results you're expecting together with the StandardTokenizer on the query side.

Create a new field with a more simplified definition (and probably the same for both index and query for now), that just consist of a whitespace tokenizer or another, more standard tokenizer - see [the reference manual for examples](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers) of the differences. You'll probably want a lowercasefilter as well.

You might run into issues with umlauts and other specific german terms, but the ICU*-range of filters and tokenizers are more international than the other ones. There's also a filter for splitting words into their components (as you have the same issue as us Norwegians, where words are written together instead of the English way of splitting them up).

The "Analysis" page under the Solr Admin is a great place to start debugging this - it'll show you exactly which transformations are made both on the index and query side, allowing you to see why terms don't match and what the terms look like at each step.

Comment: Hi Mats - sorry that I never responded to your answer. Thank you for your constructive input that helped towards resolving it!

Answer (score 0):

For latin accent characters use

```
<filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
```

this stores all words in their ASCII format with accents removed.

Your text type looks pretty unbalanced on the query side. Try something like this to start with then reindex your data (I'm currently working on a French site). I don't think the PorterStemFilterFactor is good for German, there are other stemmers that work better:-

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="40" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>   
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```